# In Java: How to change timestamp format to other format?

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp, datetime-format

How to change timestamp format to other format?

The default is "`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`" and I need '`dd-MON-yyy hh24:mi:ss`' (**like in Oracle**).

I searched on this site and I found some answers, but I could not match them to my needs.

Comment: It is impossible there is no answer to this question on SO.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja nothin is impossible :)

Comment: timestamp to date and date to formated string simply by using SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is, what you are looking for:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple Date Format like below

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss").parse(stringToBeParsed);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want GMT String format 21 Jul 2014 12:22:34 GMT,

here i used as below, passed time in long...

new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toGMTString()